# Transposing Non-Aggregate Fields in an Oracle SELECT

Tags: sql, oracle, select, pivot

For a table structured as such:

```
"Object Attribute" Table - Links objects with all of their attributes and values;
Object ID       Attribute ID    Attribute String Value  ...
1337            123             Example Object Title
1337            124             Example Object Type
1337            125             Example Object Description
1337            126             Example Object Author
0001            123             (null)
0001            124             SomeType
0001            125             This is an example record
0001            126             Jiman
0002            123             Bar
0002            124             BarType
0002            125             This is another
0002            126             Jiman
```

EDIT: Attribute ID's have the following mapping:

```
Attribute ID    Attribute Name
123             Title
124             Type
125             Description
126             Author
```

How would I compose an Oracle query that returns a transposed set of data, where the Title field is NULL?

Example output:

```
ID      Title       Type        Description             Author
0001    (null)      FooType     This is an example...   Jiman
```

Can PIVOT be used to transpose non-aggregate values (i.e., those string attributes)?

Comment: Where does the data `FooType` come from?  Is there a table that maps `Attribute_ID` 1234567890123456  to `Title`, 1234567890123458 to `Description`, etc?  Or should that mapping just be hard-coded.  Is the number of attributes you want to pivot known at compile time?

Comment: Simplified the numbers a bit - the attribute ID for "Type" is 124. I'll clarify with an edit.

Comment: Do you want the query to hard-code the mapping of the number 124 to the `Type` column?  Or do you want the query to pick that mapping up from some mapping table?  The `Attribute String Value` of `Object ID` 0001 for `Attribute ID` 124 is "SomeType".  But your expected results have a `Type` of "FooType".  Where does "FooType" come from?  Do you know at compile time all the attributes you want to be part of the pivot?

Comment: The number of pivots is known at compile time. in this example, it would be just those 4 attributes. The attribute IDs can be hard coded into the query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest approach, assuming you want the mapping from attribute ID to attribute name to be hard-coded in the query and that you know the number of elements you want in the result at compile time, would be something like

```
SELECT *
  FROM (
    SELECT object_id,
           MAX( CASE WHEN attribute_id = 123 THEN attribute_string_value ELSE NULL END) title,
           MAX( CASE WHEN attribute_id = 124 THEN attribute_string_value ELSE NULL END) type,
           MAX( CASE WHEN attribute_id = 125 THEN attribute_string_value ELSE NULL END) description,
           MAX( CASE WHEN attribute_id = 126 THEN attribute_string_value ELSE NULL END) author
      FROM your_table_name
     GROUP BY object_id )
  WHERE title IS NULL
```

If you only need to support 11g, you could use the `PIVOT` operator as well.

Comment: Thank you - but I'm getting an error 
`MAX( CASE WHEN attribute_id = 123 THEN attribute_string_value ELSE NULL ) -here- title,`

"Missing keyword"...
`AS "Title"` doesn't work either. What does it want after that `MAX()` statement?

Comment: Well done - thank you so much Justin.
One thing -  it seems to pick up a few objects where the "title" field is not null. About 99% of the records it picks up are ones with null titles... Confused a bit by this, but I can work with it.

Comment: @Jiman - If you only want rows where the `title` is NULL, I updated my answer.